# Typo3: Created page results in 404. Why? And how to fix this?

Tags: typo3

During a fresh setup of typo3 I've been asked by the installation wizzard if it should create a default main page for me. I answered with "yes". So after the installation has been completed I now have a single page in the list of pages.

I can see this page in the list of pages. It (now) contains some dummy content and is set to be visible. But whenever I try to view it (e.g. by clicking on the view icon) a 404 error shows up. It looks like as there would be be no information for the Typo3 engine to properly display the page on request.

What am I missing? How can I get this to work properly?

My configuration:

- latest stable Typo3 (downloadable at 25th of February 2020)
- NGINX-MySQL-PHP7.2 stack

Comment: Which TYPO3 version are you using? Do you work locally or on a web server?

Comment: As I said: The most recent. The one downloadable about 1 or 2 days ago. And yes, I work locally on a web server: NGINX-MySQL-PHP on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I don't think it is related to any version. My guess is that some additional settings or even plugins are required which I don't know about. What I did is downloading the latest release, installing it, creating the start page during installation, and expecting that everything should work out of the box. Which it surprisingly does not. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you access it via https or http? Did you create a Site configuration with your local hostname?

Comment: http. But that should not make any difference as the problem is: Whenever I select "view webpage" I get rerouted to a very plausible URL. For the main entry page it is "http://localhost/en/". But no content is returned. A second test page results in "http://localhost/somepage/en/" which again seems to be good. But a 404 is returned on request.

Comment: Some additional information that might hopefully help: I can "regenerate URL segment from page title". Interestingly the page title has been edited - e.g. set to "This is a test" - but on "regenerate" the URL is fabricated as "http://localhost/autogenerated-2/en". It seems the URL is generated from a different page title which does not seem to be the page title I enter. I do not see any way of modifying a page title containing this term "autogenerated": There does not seem to be a field for that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment due to reputation restriction but the URLs you claim to be plausible don't seem plausible at all.

Also, you claim that you downloaded the latest TYPO3 version. Which branch did you use, though? v9? v10? Please provide proper version information if you're asked. People trying to help you will ask for information they consider possibly relevant to your case. You're not helping by insisting that it doesn't matter or reiterating what you said when it's obvious that your information was not sufficient.

How does your page tree look like? Did you or did you not create a Site configuration as Thomas Löffler asked?